# Deleting all files of a directory over a given file size each

Tags: php

I have a bit of script that deletes all .png files in a directory:

```
foreach (glob("*.png") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
    unlink($filename);
}
```

How do I take this one step further to delete all `.png` files over a certain file size?

I have another bit of script that finds out the file size of all the files in the directory:

```
$bytes = filesize('example.png');
```

How do I combine the two?

Comment: Why don't you just run "find /path/to/dir -type f -size +1024k" as a shell command or via system() call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) statement to check whether the size is above the threshold:

```
$threshold = 1024;

foreach (glob("*.png") as $filename) {
    $size = filesize($filename);
    if ($size > $threshold) {
        unlink($filename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$maxsize = 1024; // example

foreach (glob("*.png") as $filename)
{
    $filesize = filesize($filename);
    echo "$filename size " .$filesize . "\n";
    if ($filesize > $maxsize)
        unlink($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [SPL](http://de.php.net/spl) [iterators](http://de.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php)

```
<?php
$path = '.';
class MyFilter extends FilterIterator  {
    public function accept() {
        $fi = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return strlen($fi)-4===strripos($fi, '.png') && 1024 < $fi->getSize();
    }

}
foreach (new MyFilter(new DirectoryIterator($path)) as $deleteInfo) {
    echo $deleteInfo, "\n";
}
```

(could be a bit more flexible ...but it's only an example)
If you want it to delete recursively take a look at the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/class.recursivedirectoryiterator)